# Add custom UFW rule: ufw limit ... --hitcount 'custom value'

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables, ufw

`ufw reload` reverts to standard all custom limit edits in `/etc/ufw/user.rules`.

I found a hint to write custom rules to `/etc/ufw/before.rules` (`after.rules`).
If I transfer there next rule from `/etc/ufw/user.rules`

```
-A ufw-user-input -p udp --dport 33333 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m recent --set
-A ufw-user-input -p udp --dport 33333 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m recent --update --seconds 30 --hitcount 30 -j ufw-user-limit
-A ufw-user-input -p udp --dport 33333 -j ufw-user-limit-accept
```

then

```
ufw reload
ERROR: problem running ufw-init
iptables-restore: line 86 failed: No chain/target/match by that name.
Problem running '/etc/ufw/before.rules'
```

If I understand correctly, it's because this chains

```
:ufw-user-input - [0:0]
:ufw-user-limit - [0:0]
:ufw-user-limit-accept - [0:0]
```

are missing in `/etc/ufw/before.rules`.
If I add them, there are no errors, but the rule does not work.

[I found some example with near what I need](https://45squared.com/rate-limiting-with-ufw/).
But all required chains already exist with required rules. And I don't have enough understanding of how they interact or why they don't.

After learning some iptables tutorials, I thought it might be easier to try using pure `iptables` rather than figuring out how to get around UFW restrictions. Until I checked default UFW rule set with `iptables -L`.